# Cannot create list from spreadsheet

Tags: import

We implemented a fix for this problem a few months ago (provided somewhere on the web by a member of the Excel team), and it worked just fine. Now, it doesn't (we're Army, and all sorts of things keep getting added to our networks).

Now, using either Excel or Access generates the same error:

"Cannot connect to the server at this time. Your table cannot be published."

Any ideas? We're MOSS.

Answer (score 1):

The now standard answer to this problem is to change the value of the **lver** variable in EXPToOWS.XLA to 2 (or higher). When I did this, I did not bother to comment out the first variable assignment. So, the code reads something like:

```
lver = [some expression]
```

and you are supposed to add:

```
lver = 2
```

commenting out the first assignment. I did not do so, knowing from standard programming practice that only the final action on a variable counts. Well, either not with Office code or Visual Basic or whatever, because you *must comment out the first assignment* or the fix doesn't work.